# How to count texts in pivot tables - EXCEL?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to analyze data from a survey using a pivot table.

The data consists of the following:

- 1st column is a "country" (France, UK, Italy, etc)
- 2nd column is a "color" (red, blue, pink, etc)
- 3rd column is "category 1" (values "1st position", "2nd position", "3rd position")
- 4th column is "category 2" (values "1st position", "2nd position", "3rd position")

As the data of "category 1" and "category 2" is constituted of three texts, I cannot use a pivot chart properly.

I would like to have a pivot chart where i can apply the filters "country" and "color" and have displayed the count of "1st position" vs "2nd position" vs "3rd position" for "category 1" and next to it for "category 2".

I tried all kind of pivot permutations, but it doesn't work as it's text ("1st position", "2nd position", "3rd position") and not numbers.

Comment: This is one of those situations where a picture is worth a thousand words. Can you share your data and a mock up of what you would want this pivot to look like?